# Why do I see such a huge performance difference between these functions?

Tags: c++, optimization, g++

Compiling this function with g++ works, but is pretty slow.

```cpp
void rota(double psir,double thetar,double phir,double xi,double yi,double zi,double *xf,double *yf,double *zf) {
  *xf = xi*cos(phir)*cos(psir)+yi*(-sin(phir)*cos(thetar)*cos(psir)+sin(thetar)*sin(psir))+zi*(sin(phir)*sin(thetar)*cos(psir)+cos(thetar)*sin(psir));
  *yf = xi*sin(phir)+yi*cos(phir)*cos(thetar)-zi*cos(phir)*sin(thetar);
  *zf = -xi*cos(phir)*sin(psir)+yi*(sin(thetar)*cos(psir)+cos(thetar)*sin(phir)*sin(psir))+zi*(cos(thetar)*cos(psir)-sin(thetar)*sin(phir)*sin(psir));
  return;
}
```

If I calculate the intermediate values once, then call those, my simulation runs **much** faster.

```cpp
void rota(double psir,double thetar,double phir,double xi,double yi,double zi,double *xf,double *yf,double *zf) {
  double cosf = cos(phir);
  double sinf = sin(phir);
  double cosp = cos(psir);
  double sinp = sin(psir);
  double cost = cos(thetar);
  double sint = sin(thetar);
  *xf = xi*cosf*cosp+yi*(-sinf*cost*cosp+sint*sinp)+zi*(sinf*sint*cosp+cost*sinp);
  *yf = xi*sinf+yi*cosf*cost-zi*cosf*sint;
  *zf = -xi*cosf*sinp+yi*(sint*cosp+cost*sinf*sinp)+zi*(cost*cosp-sint*sinf*sinp);
  return;
}
```

Why doesn't g++ do this optimization for me? Is there a way for me to do this more efficiently?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you set the maximum optimization level?

Comment: Try using #include <cmath> instead of #include <math.h> and call the functions using the std namespace, eg, std::cos, etc

Comment: @GearoidMurphy - I can't imagine why that would matter, but I'm open-minded. Have you seen such a difference?

Comment: I had suspected that the compiler was not taking advantage of the more concise C++ function signatures, const parameters, etc, however, it looks like NPE's optimisation solution did the trick

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've compiled your code using `gcc 4.7.2` with `-O3`. The generated `x86_64` assembly was nearly identical in the two cases.

I have then benchmarked each function by calling it 100,000,000 times.

The first version took:

```
real    0m0.216s
user    0m0.213s
sys     0m0.002s
```

while the second took:

```
real    0m0.216s
user    0m0.212s
sys     0m0.002s
```

Draw your own conclusions.

Comment: A 0.001s difference? For a computer, that's an eternity! ;)

Comment: Awesome, thanks @NPE! I'm trying to learn more, but my Google-fu is weak. What does the -O3 flag do? I get that it's Optimize, but why 3? Is there a stability/performance reason to use a different parameter there?

Comment: @MengerSponge: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.2/gcc/Optimize-Options.html#Optimize-Options